# keras -> mlmodel: coreml object has no attribute 'convert'

Tags: keras, coreml

I am trying to convert my keras model into mlmodel using coreml. However, it is saying that coremltools module has no attribute 'convert'.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

My coremltools, keras, tensorflow(tensorflow-gpu) modules are all up to date.
I am also using python 2.7.10.

I've used windows and mac, in which, neither worked. However, caffe.convert is working using a caffe model.

Code:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(MODEL_PATH)
```

As per the documentation, I expected the converters.keras.convert method to be available in coremltools.
Documentation: https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.keras.convert.html

Please help, thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
import coremltools
# from keras.models import load_model
import keras
import sys
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope

with CustomObjectScope({'relu6': keras.applications.MobileNet.relu6, 'DepthwiseConv2D': keras.applications.mobilenet.DepthwiseConv2D}):
    model = load_model('weights.hdf5')

MODEL_PATH = "data/model_wide_cifar-10_fruits_model.h5"

def main():
    """ Takes in keras model and convert to .mlmodel"""
    print(sys.version)

    # Load in keras model.
    # model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)

    # load labels
    labels=[]
    label_handler = open("fruit-labels.txt", 'r')
    for label in label_handler:
        labels.append(label.rstrip())
    label_handler.close()
    print("[INFO] Labels: {0}".format(labels))

    # Convert to .mlmodel
    coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
        model=MODEL_PATH,
        input_names="image",
        output_names="image",
        class_labels=labels)

    labels = 'fruit-labels.txt'

    # Save .mlmodel
    coreml_model.utils.save_spec('fruitclassifier.mlmodel')
```

Comment: Are you sure your method name includes the word keras, i.e. you're not calling something like `coremltools.converters.convert(...)`?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Hi, thanks for the reply. I am sure that it includes Keras. So the method works on your machine? May I know what version of coremltools you're using?

Comment: I've converted many Keras models using various versions of coremltools, with Python 2 and Python 3. Maybe you can paste the actual code you're using to do the conversion?

Comment: Hi this is the actual code i'm using to do the conversion. The same problem remains on my windows but on my mac now it says there is an AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'relu6'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I haven't used coremltools on Windows so I can't say anything useful about that. The ReLU6 error is because you're using a version of Keras that is not compatible with coremltools. (Temporarily) downgrade your Keras to 2.1.6 or whatever version it is that coremltools wants.

Comment: Hi @MatthijsHollemans, it works now!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

**The solution is to use virtualenv**. Follow the instructions from the [coremltools README](https://github.com/apple/coremltools):

### Installation

We recommend using virtualenv to use, install, or build coremltools. Be
sure to install virtualenv using your system pip.

```sh
pip install virtualenv
```

The method for installing *coremltools* follows the
[standard python package installation steps](https://packaging.python.org/installing/).
To create a Python virtual environment called `pythonenv` follow these steps:

```sh
# Create a folder for virtualenv
mkdir virtualenvs
cd virtualenvs

# Create a Python virtual environment for your Core ML project
virtualenv coremltools
```

To activate your new virtual environment and install `coremltools` in this environment, follow these steps:

```
# Active your virtual environment
source coremltools/bin/activate


# Install coremltools in the new virtual environment, pythonenv
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U coremltools==3.0b5
```

## Install keras and tensorflow

```
pip install keras tensorflow
```

### Now make sure it works. With the coremltools environment activated, run

```
>>> python
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Sep 5 2019, 14:54:52)
>>> import coremltools
>>> coremltools.converters.keras.convert()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: convert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
```

[coremltools documentation](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/)

Credit to this guys issue: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/440

Answer (score 1):

Communist Hacker's answer does not work for my current setup:

- tensorflow 2.4.1
- coremltools 4.1
- Python 3.8.7

However, after reviewing the documentation for [coremltools here](https://coremltools.readme.io/reference/convertersconvert), I was able to fix it by removing `keras` from the function and the call now works:

```
import coremltools

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.convert(model, 
                                              input_names="inputname", 
                                              output_names="outputname")
```

Running the above command now produces this in my Jupyter notebook:

```
Running TensorFlow Graph Passes: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 37.53 passes/s]
Converting Frontend ==> MIL Ops: 100%|██████████| 6/6 [00:00<00:00, 5764.05 ops/s]
Running MIL optimization passes: 100%|██████████| 17/17 [00:00<00:00, 5633.05 passes/s]
Translating MIL ==> MLModel Ops: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00, 6864.65 ops/s]
```

> Note - I am a complete noob with this, so I probably described things
> incorrectly.