# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools'

Tags: python-3.x, swift, coreml

I am new in CoreML and I am facing problem while converting file to mlmodule
my code is like this

```
import coremltools

caffe_model = ('oxford102.caffemodel','deploy.prototxt')

labels = 'flower-labels.txt'

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(
    caffe_model,
    class_label = labels,
    image_input_name = 'data'
)

coreml_model.save('FlowerClassifer.mlmodel')
```

when I write a code `python convert-script.py`
I am getting error

```
import coremltools

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coremltools'
```

I have tried everything available on internet. My python version is 3.9 and on internet it is showing that coremltools required python version 2.7
How can I solve this problem
`I am using Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing the required package.
Try

```
pip3 install coremltools

python3 convert-script.py
```

it should do the job.

Comment: already done that not work

Comment: Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: yes I am using virtual environments

Comment: Check that you've installed the package in the same environment you're running it into. Also check to be using the correct version of python to run the script, if you've multiple installed on your machine. To be sure, run it with 'python3 convert-script.py'.

Comment: showing error module 'coremltools.converters' has no attribute 'caffe'

Comment: You should use coremltools version 3. To do so, remove the version you've installed and run 'pip install coremltools==3.0'. This should fix the error whitout any other change.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools==3.0 (from versions: 4.0b1, 4.0b2, 4.0b3, 4.0, 4.1, 5.0b1, 5.0b2, 5.0b3, 5.0b4, 5.0b5, 5.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 6.0b1, 6.0b2, 6.0, 6.1)

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57816724/11153525

Comment: Not able to install 3.0. Available is from 4.0b1